# Can I blend layers by formula with brackets?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, blend-modes

I have 4 layers (A, B, C, D) which I wish to blend by the following formula (A xor B) plus (C xor D). Is it possible to accomplish this in Photoshop? I am a newbie and found that layer can only control it's blending with all underlying ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe. Sort of.

The maths for blending modes probably doesn't fit exactly what you're after. Difference is the same as XOR, and I think Screen the closest you'll get to addition.

[Screen Blending Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Screen)

[Difference Blending Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Difference)

You should be able to set up the compositing you're after by setting a group blending mode.

[image]

If you're after specific and precise values as a result, you may be better served by using something else (or writing your own little application in a high level language).

Comment: Is Difference not exactly the same as XOR?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. But I don't think screen is the same as pure addition of the values? I'll edit my response.

Comment: @e100 Difference and xor are only the same when both values are the same (eg. 100 - 100 = 0 = 100 xor 100).  "Screen" is the same as multiply, but using darkness-values instead of lightness-values (so the end-result is lighter than the originals)